# How do I map result rows of complex SQL query into custom DTO with Entity Framework Core 5.0?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a custom and somewhat complex SQL query, which I need to execute through the EF Core DbContext.

I realize the example code below could be solved using a simple .Select(), but unfortunately my actual tables are joined via magic keys and without navigational properties.

Is there anyway in which I can achieve the below below without selecting through navigational properties?

```cs
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class MyService
    {
        private readonly MyContext _context;

        public void MyMethod()
        {
            var mySql = @"SELECT Foo.FooName, Bar.BarValue FROM Foo JOIN Bar ON Foo.Key = Bar.Key";
            List<Dto> dtoList = _context.Database.MethodImLookingFor<Dto>(mySql); // Any ideas?
        }
    }
    
    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Foo> Foo { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Bar> Bar { get; set; }
    }

    // My models are only records for brevity.
    public record Foo(string Key, string FooName);
    public record Bar(string Key, string BarValue);
    public record Dto(string FooName, string BarValue);
}
```

The actual SQL query:

```sql
SELECT R.Id, S.Code, V.Code
FROM dbo.Results R
         JOIN dbo.Variable V ON V.Code = R.Value
         JOIN dbo.Severity S ON S.Id = V.SeverityId
WHERE R.Type = N'Type' AND S.Code = 'ABC' OR S.Code = 'CBA' AND R.Id = '123'
```

I already went through the [microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql). None of these map to a custom DTO without going through navigational properties.

Comment: I wouldn't, if I am honest, say that a query with a single join is "complex"; is there another query here we're missing?

Comment: I know. The actual query is quite different. I'll post the antual one in a minute.

Comment: `MethodImLookingFor<Dto>` is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql).

Comment: @RobertHarvey the example from microsoft returns the model of the Dbset<> with the other tables returned with includes. I don't have those navigational props and only need a single col from the initial DbSet.

Comment: @BjørnNørgaard a DbSet is a repository, not a table or entity. *That''s* what contains the mapping info and CRUD methods, but no data. You *have* to use it in EF Core.  On the other hand, if you have such a query and don't want to create entities and relations, why not create a *view* and map the view to an entity?

Comment: @BjørnNørgaard `returns the model of the Dbset<>` no, a DbSet isn't a *model*. The examples don't return any data directly. `FromSqlRaw` or `FromSqlInterpolated` return an `IQueryable<T>` that can be filtered. Nothing prevents you from adding a `.Select(x=>new{x.Id, x.SCode,x.VCode})` after `FromSqlRaw`.BTW that's how you query functions in EF Core

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for the suggestion. I'm already considering a view, so I might just do that. The main issue being that I like the strong typed aspect of EF with pocos. But I'll research the view way. Thanks.

Comment: @BjørnNørgaard Naturally, nothing prevents you from also getting the related data with a raw query.

Comment: In other words, you don't need navigational properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your query a little

```
SELECT R.Id, S.Code as Scode, V.Code as Vcode
FROM dbo.Results R
         JOIN dbo.Variable V ON V.Code = R.Value
         JOIN dbo.Severity S ON S.Id = V.SeverityId
WHERE R.Type = N'Type' AND S.Code = 'ABC' OR S.Code = 'CBA' AND R.Id = '123'
```

Create a new class for query result

```
[NotMapped]
public class SpResult
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public string Scode {get; set;}
public string Vcode {get; set;}
}
```

add to db context

```
 public virtual DbSet<SpResult> SpResults { get; set; }

 modelBuilder.Entity<SpResult>(e =>
   {
  e.HasNoKey();
   });
```

and finally code

```
var spResult =  _context.SpResults.FromSqlRaw(mysql).ToList();

List<Dto> dtoList = spResult.Select( i=> new Dto
{
 ID = i.Id,
 FooName =i.Scode,
 BarValue=i.Vcode,
 
}).ToList();
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also cause a new table to be created when a migration is created?

Comment: I don't think so. I used it many times and never had any problem. It has [NotMapped] attribute

Answer (score 0):

What you do is use [Dapper](https://github.com/DapperLib/Dapper). A lot faster than EF, and you access it via the EF dbcontext - so its really a library that extends EF, no need to create new connections or anything like that.

It works really well.

```
public class Dog
{
    public int? Age { get; set; }
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public float? Weight { get; set; }

    public int IgnoredProperty { get { return 1; } }
}

var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
var dog = connection.Query<Dog>("select Age = @Age, Id = @Id", new { Age = (int?)null, Id = guid });
```